# Trying to run a truffle test after successful compile I have this Error: Invalid number of parameters for "undefined". Got 0 expected 1!

Tags: truffle-test

Here is my deploy hello js file

```
const hello = artifacts.require('./HelloWorld');

module.exports = function(deployer){
  deployer.deploy(hello);
};
```

And here is the contract code

```
pragma solidity^0.5.16;

contract HelloWorld {

    string private name;
    mapping (address => uint256) public balance;

    constructor(string memory _name) public {
      name = _name;
      balance[msg.sender] = 1000;
    }

    function getName() public view returns (string memory) {
      return name;
    }

    function setName(string memory _name) public {
      name = _name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass one string when deploying HelloWorld since its constructor receives one parameter.

```
constructor(string memory _name) public {
```

For example it  should look like this

```
const hello = artifacts.require('./HelloWorld');

module.exports = function(deployer){
  deployer.deploy(hello, "zzzz");
};
```